# Why am I receiving an error when trying to use DisplayMetrics in Android?

Tags: android

I'm just starting with Android programming, and I receive an error in the following code:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
```

The first line is fine according to Eclipse.  But in the second line it's telling me that "getWindowManager"'s return type is missing.  I don't understand this.  When I search the internet on how to use this code, everyone is doing the same thing.  Yet Eclipse is giving me an error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If this code is being used in a View instead of an Activity, you need to do something like

```
((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
```

or

```
((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
  .getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
```

Answer (score 1):

Providing more code would help people to help you debugging.

From your OP,

> But in the second line it's telling me
>   that "getWindowManager"'s return type
>   is missing

[getWindowManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getWindowManager%28%29) is a method of `Activity` so make sure you have your code inside an activity (`extends Activity`))